# Moving an edge without "humps"

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

I need to move an edge back along Y axis (as you can see on picture), but on that part's appearing humps. How can I get ride of them and keep it straight?

[image]

Comment: Hello sir. consider uploading your blendfile here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ co others can take a closer look :).

Comment: I'm not sure there's any other way to do it than manually